# Programmatically update field group description on entity view screen

Tags: 9

Is there a way to programmatically update the field description for a field group tab on the entity form edit view?

It feels/looks like I should be using something along the lines here

```
  $form_display = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('entity_form_display')
    ->load('node.page.default');

$item = $form_display->getComponent('third_party_settings');
$item->setComponent('third_party_settings', ['field_group' => ['group_additional_body'=>['format_settings' => ['description'=> ['Fieldset Group Description]]]]);
$item-save();
```

Not sure how/if this is possible.

Comment: I think you can do that using HOOK_form_alter(). I'm not sure if it would work for your use case.

Comment: Thats an idea I had not thought of that. I was trying to do this in an install hook but maybe runtime as opposed to install time might be quicker/easer.